# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, cursor

I am pretty new at PL/SQL, so I am pretty sure that problem is in syntax somewhere.

I have two tables. For every row in the first table I should compute values X, Y, Z using data from the second table, and insert it into the first table. In the second table time values are not the same, so I should use the closest smaller value from it.

I am getting either "Encounter the symbol "END" "error or the page just dies, if I change something. Anyone can help me?

My code looks like:

```
    DECLARE

Nr Varchar(5) := 'G01'; /*manuali*/
pi NUMBER :=3.14159265359;
A NUMBER;
tk NUMBER;
time NUMBER;  
n0 NUMBER;
n NUMBER;
M NUMBER;
E NUMBER;
i NUMBER;
E_old NUMBER;
dE NUMBER;
v NUMBER;
phi NUMBER;
u NUMBER;
r NUMBER;
x1 NUMBER;
y1 NUMBER;
x NUMBER;
y NUMBER;
z JP_BROAD_KOORD.z%TYPE;
GM NUMBER := 3.986005e14; /*m^3/s^2*/
Omegae_dot NUMBER := 7.2921151467e-5; /*rad/s*/
M0 JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.MO%TYPE;
roota JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.SQRTA%TYPE;
deltan JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.DELTA_N%TYPE;  
ecc JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.ECCENTRICITY%TYPE;
omega JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.OMEGA%TYPE;
cuc JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.CUC%TYPE;
cus JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.CUS%TYPE;
crc JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.CRC%TYPE;
crs JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.CRS%TYPE;
i0 JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.IO%TYPE;
idot JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.IDOT%TYPE;
cic JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.CIC%TYPE;
cis JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.CIS%TYPE;
Omega0 JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.OMEGA2%TYPE;
Omegadot JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.OMEGA_DOT%TYPE;
toe JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.TOE%TYPE;
CURSOR BrCursor is
select TIME
from JP_BROAD_KOORD; 
CURSOR NavCursor is
select Mo, Sqrta, delta_n, eccentricity, omega, cuc, cus, crc, crs, io, idot, cic, cis, omega2, omega_dot, toe
from JP_BROADCAST_NAV2
where toe=(select max(toe) from JP_BROADCAST_NAV2 where toe < TIME and Satelita_nr=Nr) and Satelita_nr=Nr; 
BEGIN
FOR item in BrCursor
LOOP
OPEN NavCursor;
A := roota*roota;
tk := time-toe;
n0 := sqrt(GM/(A*A*A));
n := n0+deltan;
M := M0+n*tk;
M := remainder(M+2*pi,2*pi);
E := M;
loop
   E_old := E;
   E := M+ecc*sin(E);
   dE := remainder(E-E_old,2*pi);
   exit when abs(dE) < 1.e-12;
   end loop;
E := remainder(E+2*pi,2*pi);
v := atan2(sqrt(1-ecc*ecc)*sin(E), cos(E)-ecc);
phi := v+omega;
phi := remainder(phi,2*pi);
u := phi              + cuc*cos(2*phi)+cus*sin(2*phi);
r := A*(1-ecc*cos(E)) + crc*cos(2*phi)+crs*sin(2*phi);
i := i0+idot*tk       + cic*cos(2*phi)+cis*sin(2*phi);
Omega := Omega0+(Omegadot-Omegae_dot)*tk-Omegae_dot*toe;
Omega := remainder(Omega+2*pi,2*pi);
x1 := cos(u)*r;
y1 := sin(u)*r;
x := 0.000001*(x1*cos(Omega)-y1*cos(i)*sin(Omega));
y := 0.000001*(x1*sin(Omega)+y1*cos(i)*cos(Omega));
z := 0.000001*(y1*sin(i));
INSERT INTO JP_BROAD_KOORD (X, Y, Z)
VALUES (x, y, z);
CLOSE NavCursor;
end loop;
end loop;
END;
```

Comment: There is redundant `end loop` before final `end`. Usually proper code formatting (indentation especially) helps avoiding such class of errors in pl/sql.

Comment: Why `n NUMBER` but `M NUMBER;`? What is your naming system?

Answer (score 1):

> "I am pretty new at plsql"

Now's the time to acquire good habits.

Consistent indentation is more than pedantry: it can help us identify problems in our code.
Label loops: they really help us match the head and end of loops, which is particularly useful with long chunks of code like you have here.

Employing either of these techniques might have helped you spot you had an orphaned `END LOOP` statement.

```
DECLARE   
    Nr Varchar(5) := 'G01'; /*manuali*/
    ...
    toe JP_BROADCAST_NAV2.TOE%TYPE;
    CURSOR BrCursor is
        select TIME
        from JP_BROAD_KOORD;    
    CURSOR NavCursor is
        select Mo, Sqrta, delta_n, eccentricity, omega, cuc, cus, crc, crs, io, idot, cic, cis, omega2, omega_dot, toe
        from JP_BROADCAST_NAV2
        where toe=(select max(toe) 
                   from JP_BROADCAST_NAV2 
                   where toe < TIME 
                   and Satelita_nr=Nr)
         and Satelita_nr=Nr; 
BEGIN
    << br_koord >> 
    FOR item in BrCursor  LOOP
        OPEN NavCursor;
        A := roota*roota;
        ...
        E := M;
        << de_calc >>
        LOOP
           E_old := E;
           ...
           exit when abs(dE) < 1.e-12;
        END LOOP de_calc;
        E := remainder(E+2*pi,2*pi);
        ...
        z := 0.000001*(y1*sin(i));
        INSERT INTO JP_BROAD_KOORD (X, Y, Z)
        VALUES (x, y, z);
        CLOSE NavCursor;
    END LOOP br_koord;
END;
```